# PHP Imagick GIF Animation Is Not Preserved

Tags: php, gif, imagick, animated-gif

I am having a bit up trouble upload gifs and keeping their animation. My code looks like this:

```
$image = new Imagick($data['file']);
$object -> uploadFile('test.gif', $image -> getImageBlob());
```

And the gif goes not seem to be preserved when the getImageBlob() is used. Ive event tried:

```
$image = new Imagick($data['file']);
$image = $image->coalesceImages(); 
$image = $image->deconstructImages(); 
$object -> uploadFile('test.gif', $image -> getImageBlob());
```

Is there way I can preseve the gif when using getImageBlob()?

Comment: Could you possibly provide one of the gifs that's breaking? That kind of thing is usually due to non-similar frames.

Comment: No, I've tried on multiple different gifs

Answer (score 5):

Try [`Imagick::getImagesBlob`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagesblob.php) instead of [`Imagick::getImageBlob`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimageblob.php). `getImagesBlob` will return the sequence of loaded images, as opposed to just a single image; in this case, the each frame in the GIF.

A quick check with PHP 5.5.7 and PECL imagick 3.1.2 reveals two different behaviors:

```
$image = new Imagick('test.gif');
var_dump(strlen($image->getImagesBlob())); // int(4316519)
var_dump(strlen($image->getImageBlob()));  // int(61413)
```